# One button shows for a fraction of a second before another hides even though they depend on the same function

Tags: angularjs, ng-show, ng-hide

When I click on the button to go to new slide, the second button appears for a fraction of a second before the first button disappears. This is despite them having `ng-show` directives that rely on the same  `functionvm.onLastSlide()`.

```
<button ng-show="!vm.onLastSlide()" ng-click="vm.nextSlide()">{{'Guide.Next' | i18n}}</button>
<button ng-show="vm.onLastSlide()" ng-click="vm.close()">{{'Guide.Create' | i18n}}</button>
```

I don't know what is causing this problem in my situation. But it is a complex situation. The buttons are in a popup that has a scope of its own.

Is there any way to make them show and hide at the same time regardless of any other circumstances?

Comment: Are there any kind of animations going on?

Comment: Can't reproduce based upon this: https://jsfiddle.net/r0m4n/6p821y6m/ Make a jsfiddle and post it

Comment: No animations that I know on. But it is a scope within a scope deal. The circumstances are complex. It's inside a big application. So I don't know how I would recreate the problem in jsfiddle. Hence my question is about what can cause this behavior and if there is any general solution